# TableView doesn´t reload after modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im making a program where im practicing UIPopoverController's for iPad

in the first popover i have a tableView with some cells , what i want to do is to call a new view with a textfield so i can add new cells with the textfield text .

The problem i have is that when i dismiss the second view the tableView is not updated . I can't call reloadData because the first view don't call "viewWillAppear" ou any other .

In the iphone simulator it works well because iphone don't use uiPopoverController but in iPad i have to dismiss the first popover and the view only reloads when i enter the second time.

I know by reading some posts that its possible to use notification center to make it happen but i don't know how

My code is this

-first view , the tableView

BNRAssetTypeViewController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class BNRItem;

@interface BNRAssetTypeViewController : UITableViewController 

@property (nonatomic,strong) BNRItem *item;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^dismissBlock)(void);

@end
```

BNRAssetTypeViewController.m

```
#import "BNRAssetTypeViewController.h"
#import "BNRItem.h"
#import "BNRItemStore.h"
#import "BNRDetailViewController.h"
#import "AddNewAssetedTypeViewController.h"


@implementation BNRAssetTypeViewController

-(instancetype)init
{
//Chamar o designated initializer
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
if (self) {

//Titulo
UINavigationItem *navItem = self.navigationItem;
navItem.title=@"New Asseted Type";

//Criar um novo bar button que faz novo item do lado direito
UIBarButtonItem *bbi =[[UIBarButtonItem    alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                   target:self  action:@selector(addNewAssetedType)];
//meter do lado direito
navItem.rightBarButtonItem=bbi;


}
return self;
}
-(instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
return [self init];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad");
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

 }

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
NSLog(@"ViewwillApear");

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
NSLog(@"ViewDidApear");
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore]allAssetTypes]count];
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSArray *allAssetTypes = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore]allAssetTypes];
NSManagedObject *assetType = allAssetTypes[indexPath.row];

// Use key-value coding to get the asset type's label
NSString *assetLabel = [assetType valueForKey:@"label"];
cell.textLabel.text = assetLabel;

// Checkmark the one that is currently selected
if (assetType == self.item.assetType) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;



NSArray *allAssets = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore]allAssetTypes];
NSManagedObject *assetType = allAssets[indexPath.row];
self.item.assetType=assetType;

if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    self.dismissBlock();
} else {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


}

-(void)addNewAssetedType{

AddNewAssetedTypeViewController *anatvc = [[AddNewAssetedTypeViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:anatvc];


 navController.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

-The second View

AddNewAssetedTypeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AddNewAssetedTypeViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,copy) void (^dismissBlock)(void);

@end
```

AddNewAssetedTypeViewController.m

```
#import "AddNewAssetedTypeViewController.h"
#import "BNRItemStore.h"
#import "BNRAssetTypeViewController.h"

@interface AddNewAssetedTypeViewController ()


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation AddNewAssetedTypeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    UIBarButtonItem *doneItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(save:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=doneItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                               target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=cancelItem;

}
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

[self.view endEditing:YES];

[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] createAssetType:self.textField.text];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

-(void)cancel:(id)sender
{

[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                  completion:nil];
}
-(void)save:(id)sender
{

[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                  completion:nil];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!
You can fire a notification using `NSNotificationCenter` when something is added in the popover. First, register the first view controller to observe for that notification. In the first VC retain a reference to the observer you'll register later on:

```
@implementation BNRAssetTypeViewController {
    id _observer;
}
```

In viewWillAppear:

```
_observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"somethingAddedNotification"
                    object:nil
                     queue:nil
                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
{
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

In viewWillDisappear:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:_observer];
}
```

Then in the method `save:` in the second view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"somethingAddedNotification" object:nil];
```

Disclaimer: untested code. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It´s working now , thank you soo much ! I knew NSNotification center could work but i couldn't make it happen. For future people seeing thins question the code you have to place in the save method needs to be after the dismiss code . Thank you once again Matias R